# Android notification importance cannot be changed

Tags: java, android

Code Summary:

```java
NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
 NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
...
int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_TITLE, importance);
manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
notification.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
manager.notify(notificationId, 0, notification.build());
```

`manager.getImportance()` returns always 3(IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT).
How can I change importance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Once you submit the channel to the NotificationManager, **you cannot**
>   change the importance level. **However, the user can change their
>   preferences for your app's channels at any time.**

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

The solution is to guide user to notification settings and allow him to modify your channel. To open a channel in android settings there is an intent:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
      intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, getActivity().getPackageName());
      intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, channelID);
      if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
          startActivity(intent);
      } else {
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.not_found, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
}
```

Another solution is to create a new channel and use that channel but user always sees all channels that you have created in Android Settings

Comment: @A.N Another solution is to create a new channel and use that channel but user always sees all channels that you have created in Android Settings